# how to find column with more than 60 percent zero

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
    df<-structure(list(X1 = c(1.419, 1.294, 3.558, 0.17, 0, 0.03, 0.129, 
0, 0.105, 0, 1.812, 0.237, 0, 5.241), X2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.175, 
0, 0, 0.073, 0, 0.079, 0, 3.204, 0.062, 0, 3.864), X3 = c(0, 
0.081, 0.291, 0.013, 0, 0, 0.023, 0, 0.12, 0, 2.13, 0, 0, 4.383
), X4 = c(0.868, 0.472, 0.002, 0.604, 0.343, 0, 0.097, 0, 0.149, 
0, 2.741, 0.1, 0, 5.231)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

I want to know which rows have more than 60 percent of the row az 0

I know how to remove those with complete zero but I cannot find those that have 50 or 60% zero In the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is `colMeans` on a logical `matrix`

```
thresh <- 0.5
names(df)[colMeans(df == 0) >= thresh]
```

If we want to find the rows having more than 50% 0s, do the same with `rowMeans`

```
rowMeans(df == 0) >= thresh
```

Comment: I want to know which rows have more than 50% of zeros

Comment: @Learner. But your title says about column

Comment: @Learner It is a bit confusing from the wordings.  Can you show the expected output for the data you showed

Comment: when I want to substract those from matrix , should I do this `50% <- df[50,]`

Comment: @Learner If you meant to remove those rows having 50% or more 0s, `df[rowMeans(df == 0) < thresh,]`